# How to check if a variable has a map available in rails? In other words, if a variable is mappable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to deal with a legacy method which accepts a variable and returns the `variable.amount.to_s`. But now with some changes, the variable can also be an active record relation.

I basically want to be able to do something like this:

```rb
def method(variable)
  if variable has map?
    variable.map { |v| v.amount.to_f }.reduce(:+)
    variable.to_s
  else
    variable.amount.to_s
  end
end
```

but I am unable to figure out what that `if` condition should be ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can test for the method directly with [`respond_to?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-respond_to-3F).

```
if variable.respond_to?(:map)
```

Or you can check that it is [Enumerable](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html) which provides a large suite of methods used for iteration, including [`map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-map).

```
if variable.is_a?(Enumerable)
```

The advantage of Enumerable is it tells you more about the object, and you can be more sure that its `map` is the map you expect and not just some method that happens to be named `map`. The disadvantage is it will miss anything which is not `Enumerable` but does implement an applicable `map`; I can't think of a case where that should happen.

Comment: Thank you! `variable.is_a?(Enumerable)` is exactly what I was looking for.